# Ios раскрывающийся список Srotyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Вообщем такая проблема нужно в Storyborad для меню создать раскрывающиеся списки ну типо на них нажимаешь и он раскладывается ну думаю понятно. Я знаю что их можно как-то через UITableView делать, но как точно хз. Прошу помощи.

Вот примерно что мне надо:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понятно, без скриншота. Но предположу два варианта:

1 Если вы имеете боковой бар то гуглите `swift slide menu`. А я посоветовал бы [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController)

2 Если вы "выпадашку" имеете ввиду то гуглите `swift drop down menu`. Как вариант можно заюзать [эту библиотеку](https://github.com/maxkonovalov/MKDropdownMenu) или [эту](https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown). Удачи.

Answer (score 0):

Сделать такое через UITableView не составит труда, но будут дополнительные флаги для рендеринга использовать.

1. Каждый раздел - это секция, сколько разделов столько и секций.
2. Нужен массив булевых типов - по индексу секции флаг - развернут или скрыт. На swift - [Bool]
3. В каждой секции кол-во ячеек: 1 если свернута или кол-во подсекций + 1 если раскрыто. Состояние свернутости можно получить из пункта 2.
4. По клике на первую ячейку (всегда видимая часть) - меняй значение флага для этой секции на противоположное и сразу обновляй таблицу. Для начала сделай просто reloadData(), потом добавь анимацию (пункт 5) после того как все остальное работает.
5. Анимацию можно добавить по быстрому - reloadSection с указанием одной секции которая изменилась. Но лучше анимация будет работать если учитывая флаг явно в один коммит добавишь / удалишь все под пункты с анимацией.

В методе получения секции всегда 1й row (индекс 0) - основной пункт, начиная с индекса 1 - подпункты секции, для них уже другой дизайн.